# How to trigger an alarm clock on iOS that will resume my radio stream? (like tuneIn Radio)

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I am wondering how I can program an alarm clock on iOS that will resume my radio stream. An example of this behaviour is the alarm implementation in the TuneIn Radio app.

I tried using UILocalNotification and resuming playback in the didReceiveLocalNotification message but this is only called once we dismiss the alert from the notification. I would like to have this called without the alert.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this and you need a legitimate work around.  I've recently solved this problem for an app that needs to achieve the same functionality without the streaming radio bit. You would take your application into the background the second the user sets their alarm.  This would loop all night by playing silent audio tracks and you would do some date math and configure your radio stream to start playing after the final (Calculated) silent audio track fires off.  You can use audiodidfinishplaying to listen for each silent loop's end during the night.  Hope this helps.

One other quick note:  I would reference the documentation to setup your app, in particular your plist to get it configured properly for background audio.

Comment: This solution is not legitimate and got rejected by the appStore.